# How to create PDA with solana CLI?

Tags: solana-cli

I see how I can create a PDA then use this PDA to call my program with the JS client, but how can I do it with the solana CLI ?

`solana create-address-with-seed "test" 4hN644A4rMrusDEHgAUth5ubTKD7PtRLRL8LBXsTg8Gw` create the address but not the account from what I understand. After I get the address from the past command, I cannot find the account with `solana account`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an account with the solana cli. You can only generate an address with the CLI and find accounts that already exist

Answer (score 2):

You cannot initialize PDAs outside of programs. You need to have an instruction in your program that initializes it for you/ modify and upon calling that program. Your PDA will be initialized.

For further information : [What is a Program Derived Address (PDA) exactly?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-program-derived-address-pda-exactly)

Comment: I just deployed a program, then created a PDA knowing the programId of that program in my client code (JS). So I succeed to initialize a PDA in client code from what I understand.