# what is the relation between Signers & Wallets in testing

Tags: anchor, testing, anchor-test

1. What is the difference between `provider.wallet.Pubkey` ,   `provider.Pubkey`  and `anchor.web3.Keypair.generate().publicKey` at testing? I am confused where to use each one of them because they look the same .

My rust code :

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SignUp<'info> {

#[account(init,
          payer = authority, 
          space = size_of::<UserAccount>() + USER_NAME_LENGTH + EMAIL_LENGTH + NAME_LENGTH + PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH + 8 + 8 + 2 + 2 )]
pub user: Account<'info, UserAccount>,

// Associated user with the smart contract who paid transaction fee 
#[account(mut)]
pub authority: Signer<'info>,

// It's the smart contract that we have 
pub system_program: Program<'info , System>,


pub clock: Sysvar<'info , Clock>
}
```

And my test:

```
        await program.methods.signUp("reasje", "09146979106", "").accounts({
        user: user.publicKey,
        authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        clock: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
    }).signers([user]).rpc({ skipPreflight: true });
```

2. Why the `authority` (Signer) should be provider.wallet.publickey (Others give `Error: Raw transaction 2L8Zk5tBUhz57dDBAKVGW6JXkFZhSb1mX8izMnm5dBjFaBvznji6S9AEpFTtJh4C6NHBGCtjuVgKN1yJ6VWytTwL failed ({"err":{"InstructionError":[0,"InvalidArgument"]}})` error), but the account is being created with user wallet.
3. What is the point of using `.signers([user])` ? (Which not using it gives ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`Error: Signature verification failed` error), while i am signing the trx with the authority
4. Why deleting the `authority:` from the test works fine too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between provider.wallet.Pubkey , provider.Pubkey and anchor.web3.Keypair.generate().publicKey ...

A crypto wallet is a device or application that stores a collection of keys and can be used to send, receive, and track ownership of cryptocurrencies. Wallets can take many forms. A wallet might be a directory or file in your computer's file system, a piece of paper, or a specialized device called a hardware wallet. There are also various smartphone apps and computer programs that provide a user-friendly way to create and manage wallets.

A keypair is a securely generated private key and its cryptographically-derived public key. A private key and its corresponding public key are together known as a keypair. A wallet contains a collection of one or more keypairs and provides some means to interact with them.

> Why the authority (Signer) should be provider.wallet.publickey

`provider.wallet.publickey` is always a `signer` (in anchor). Since you're using it to pay for transaction fees. In this case, you can use another `publickey` but it has to be a `signer` in your transaction by adding it to `.signers([<signer>])`

> What is the point of using .signers([user]) ?

Besides the `provider.wallet.publickey` which is a `signer` by default in **anchor tests**. You can add other signers (like I mentioned before) by adding there to `.signers([])`

Here we need `user` as a signer because we are modifying that `account` (initializing). We don't need it as a signer if it's a [PDA](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-program-derived-address-pda-exactly)

> Why deleting the authority: from the test works fine too?

`provider.wallet.publickey` is signer by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but for the first question your answer is unrelated, What i meant by that question is if they are all wallets what is the motivation to have three of them ? However with your answer it's clear now, but only  `provider.Pubkey`'s usage is unclear to me .

Comment: `A wallet contains a collection of one or more keypairs and provides some means to interact with them.`. I'm not sure about `provider.Pubkey` tho, never used it :))