# Base Account in Production

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, nft

Im finishing up a test app and want to launch it online. My app currently uses the same keypair so each time I start the app I have the same results.

Im wondering if this same keypair should be shared across all users of my app or does each user need to create their own "Base Account".

Also if the clients each have a different Keypair, how will they see each other's minted nfts?

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this issue, you have to use [PDAs](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-program-derived-address-pda-exactly)

**example in anchor**

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Deposit<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut,seeds=["sol_bank".as_bytes()],bump)]
    pub sol_bank: SystemAccount<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Here everyone who calls the Deposit instruction has to pass sol_bank with seeds as "sol_bank". You can store data in a PDA that way you know all data would be shared across all users.

Comment: Thanks @vicyn 
In this setup, the sol_bank would be the keypair for my bank correct?

Comment: Also should the user's client generate a new key pair every time they access the site? I couldn't find guidance on 'base accounts'

Comment: Pda are not keypairs, they are off the curve. They can sign transactions only in their derived program. (You don't have a private key for pda)