# How to figure out if an address is an associated token address owned by the running program?

Tags: rust, token

I wonder as to how to check that a provided `AccountInfo` to a program points out to the account of the same program (that one which is running, so that it is its own associated token address)?

I'm trying to write a program which would be completely stateless in the sense of absence of any account for common variables, so I would appreciate to know how to check it within runtime without any prerequisites like to store it somewhere and then check the address. I wonder how to check it on the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you understand [PDAs](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-program-derived-address-pda-exactly)

an Associated Token Account (ATA) is a PDA derived from the [SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID](https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account#finding-the-associated-token-account-address) and with seeds:

- wallet address
- TOKEN_PROGRAM
- mint address

This makes it for each user, a unique ATA will be created for that mint. Rather than creating multiple token accounts and having a hard time managing them.

If you are using Anchor, you can simply check if an account is ATA by doing

```
  #[account(init,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = token_a_mint,
        associated_token::authority = swap_account,
    )]
  pub token_a_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
```

Comment: actually I do not use Anchor

Comment: in that case, you have to check that the address matches that pda with the seeds I mentioned above.