# How to initialize an Associated Token Account (ATA) in anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, token

I want to initialize an Associated Token Account in anchor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you understand [PDAs](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-program-derived-address-pda-exactly)

an Associated Token Account (ATA) is a PDA derived from the [SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID](https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account#finding-the-associated-token-account-address) and with seeds:

- wallet address
- TOKEN_PROGRAM
- mint address

This makes it for each user, a unique ATA will be created for that mint. Rather than creating multiple token accounts and having a hard time managing them.

If you are using Anchor, you can simply check if an account is ATA by doing

```
  #[account(init,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = token_a_mint,
        associated_token::authority = swap_account,
    )]
  pub token_a_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
  pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
```