# Payable function equivalents?

Tags: anchor

Does anyone know of any good code examples of "payable functions" being used in Solana?  I realize that payable functions are specifically a Solidity thing.  I just want to understand what the best practices are for this.

i.e.

I want to have a function that only runs when a certain amount of lamports are sent along with the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Solana uses `System` program for this purpose. Your program will need to invoke System Program via a CPI call. CPI or Cross-program invocations allow programs to invoke other programs directly. You can use `transfer` instruction from System Program. Implementation of transfer instruction is as follows:

```
pub fn transfer(
    from_pubkey: &Pubkey,
    to_pubkey: &Pubkey,
    lamports: u64
 ) -> Instruction
```

More about Transfer:  https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/system_instruction/fn.transfer.html

You can add the transfer instruction within the body of your program's function/instruction which will ensure that the whole instruction will only be executed if transfer instruction is successfully executed i.e. the lamports have been successfully transferred.

Here's an example of SOL transfer in Anchor;

```
use anchor_lang::system_program;
....
let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), 
system_program::Transfer {
    from: ctx.accounts.sender.to_account_info(),
    to: ctx.accounts.receiver.to_account_info(),
});
system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;
....

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SendSol<'info> {
    sender: Signer<'info>,
    receiver: AccountInfo<'info>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>
}
```

Another difference between Ethereum and Solana is the differentiation between logic and storage so unlike Ethereum where you transfer ETH to contract's address, you transfer SOL to a PDA account on the behalf of the Program on Solana.

Comment: I put this in a function and called it. I am getting the following error:                                  
Error: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionFallbackNotFound. Error Number: 101. Error Message: Fallback functions are not supported.                                                                           Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

Solana is quite different from Ethereum, Solana doesn't implement payable functions. When sending a transaction you specify the accounts you want to pass to the program. Those accounts can be a `signer`.

If you want to transfer SOL from an Account. It has to be either a `signer` or a [PDA](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-program-derived-address-pda-exactly).